# Why do bounties vary?

Tags: support, bounty

When setting up a bounty on a question, usually it costs 50 of Your reputation. But sometimes it costs more.

I cannot find anything in the faq about this.

Why does this vary? Is it depending on your total reputation? Or on the bounties, you already set?

Comment: Next bounty you set needs to be higher

Comment: @rene until you're all-in !

Answer (score 46, accepted):

From the answer on [Clever bounty reputation hack](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/64826)

> - If you are placing a bounty on a question you answered, your minimum spend is 100
> - If you are placing a repeat bounty on a question, your minimum spend doubles till it reaches 500

See also the MSE FAQ [How does the bounty system work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16065/how-does-the-bounty-system-work)